# printing even array from given array

Tags: java

I have following input sequence `4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 19`. I would like to print only even values.

I am using this code:

```
 class EvenArray {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         int arr[] = { 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 19 };

         int a = arr.length;

         int eve[] = new int[a];

         for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++) {
             if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                 for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                     eve[j] = arr[i];
                 }
             }
             System.out.println(eve[i]);
         }
     }
 }
```

I get follwoing result `4, 2, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0` but I expect `4, 2, 6, 8`. Zeros are not required. What went wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your not getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: check the condition `if(arr[i] != 0)` before assigning value to `eve` array

Comment: `System.out.println(eve[]);` isn't valid syntax. To print an array, you are looking for `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(eve));`

Comment: 0%2 is equals to 0 that is why arr[i] % 2 == 0 is being true

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `eve` array has the same length of the original `arr`, so the remaining values are 0 [by default `ìnt` array initialization].

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating the loop equal to the size of the array, so to exclude 0 you need to add the condition as below :

```
     for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
      {
          if(arr[i]%2==0) 
          { 
              for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) 
              {
                  eve[j] = arr[i]; 
              } 
          } 
          if(eve[i]==0)
              continue;
          System.out.println(eve[i]); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned only about the even numbers other than zero and do not want to have any other elements, i suggest you to use an `ArrayList` where you do not need to know the total size initially.

```
ArrayList<Integer> even=new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
{
  if(arr[i]%2==0 && arr[i]!=0)
  even.add(arr[i]);
}
```

To print the values

```
for(Integer i:even)
{
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
class evenArray
{
    public Static void main(String args[])
    {
        int arr[]={4,2,3,5,6,8,19};
        int a = arr.length;
        int eve[]= new int[a];
        for(int i=0,j=0;i<a;i++)
         {
            if(arr[i]!=0 && arr[i]%2==0)
            {
                    eve[j] = arr[i];
                    j++;                    
            }

        }

     //Printing elements
     for(int k=0;k<eve.length;k++){
         System.out.println(eve[k]);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess, `System.out.println(eve[i]);`?

Answer (score 0):

You have those 0s because you're printing the amount of elements you have initially even though you might have less even numbers and by default an int array is initialized with 0s.

Assuming that you want a method that works for every input it should look something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class EvenArray {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
     int arr[] = { 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 19 };

     int a = arr.length;

     ArrayList<Integer> eve = new ArrayList<Integer>();

     for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
         if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                 eve.add(arr[i]);
         }
     }
     System.out.println(eve);
  }
 }
```

**Notes:**
Here I use ArrayList because you don't need to specify its size when initializing  (to use it you need the import on the first line of code)

On the first for you also had i <= a, on the condition, which would try to access a non existing position and give an indexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

And for a truly OTT solution:

```
interface Filter<T> {

    public boolean accept(T f);
}

static class FilteredNumbers implements Iterable<Number> {

    private final List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Filter filter;

    public FilteredNumbers(List<Number> numbers, Filter filter) {
        this.numbers.addAll(numbers);
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    public FilteredNumbers(Number[] numbers, Filter filter) {
        this(Arrays.asList(numbers), filter);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Number> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Number>() {
            int i = 0;
            Number next = null;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                if (next == null) {
                    for (; i < numbers.size() && next == null; i++) {
                        Number n = numbers.get(i);
                        if (filter.accept(n)) {
                            next = n;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return next != null;
            }

            @Override
            public Number next() {
                Number n = hasNext() ? next : null;
                next = null;
                return n;
            }

        };
    }

}

static class EvenNumbers extends FilteredNumbers {
    public EvenNumbers (Number[] numbers) {
        super(numbers, new Filter<Number>() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(Number f) {
                return f != null && (f.intValue() & 1) == 0;
            }

        });
    }
}
```